# Extensión y origen de "orto"

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, etimología

Últimamente he visto cada vez más extendido en Colombia el término *orto* para referirse a las partes traseras de una persona.  Originalmente lo escuchaba sólo de argentinos.

Siempre asumí que venía de la raíz etimológica *orto-* de origen griego y que significa *correcto*, *derecho*, *recto*; y que el término empezó a substituir, en la jerga porteña, al recto anatómico, a esa última parte del intestino grueso que termina en el ano.

¿Es correcta esta etimología?  Además de Argentina y Colombia ¿dónde más es común este término con este significado?

---

Encuentro que *orto* sí es una palabra en español, derivada del latín *ortus*, y significa el punto donde un astro *sale* o *nace*.  No parece, sin embargo, que esta sea la etimología de *orto* con el significado de *ano* o *nalgas*.

Comment: En respuesta a tu pregunta sobre dónde más es común el término orto con este significado, simplemente confirmar que en España no es correcto y nadie lo usa... A no ser que se esté imitando a un argentino, claro... :-)

Comment: "Orto" también se usa en Chile.

Comment: Yo creo q si formamos una "o" con los dedos, direccionando los restantes hacia abajo, nos referiremos exclusivamente al ano y referencialmente al del homosexual. Tal vez alguien asoció esa "o" con el término orto q suena un poco vulgar. En Perú oí esa referencia desde los años 80.

Answer (score 7):

La expresión (grosera) es muy usada actualmente en Argentina, aunque no hace mucho. El origen de estas "malas palabras" frecuentemente es incierto, y creo que este es el caso.

La asociación con "recto" me parece muy poco natural, estas palabras no suelen nacer por estos caminos.

Más probable (aunque nada conclusiva) me parece la otra explicación que encuentro en la red: en italiano "orto" significa "huerto" o "jardín de flores" (ten en cuenta que el italiano tiene mucha influencia, por vía de la inmigración, en el lunfardo de Buenos Aires). La asociación sería irónica, por la alusión al aroma de las flores.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sabía (puramente anecdótico), la relación con la palabra huerto era relacionado a la cosecha: al agacharse los trabajadores mostraban sus partes.

Comment: @Alpha: interesante, me resulta más o menos igual de plausible que la otra.

Answer (score 5):

Yo coincido con que orto es sinónimo de recto, en la alusión anatómica a la última parte del intestino.

Orto es un radical derivado del griego *orthos*, que significa recto, derecho, estricto, canónico...

Es común encontrarlo en palabras compuestas como ortofonista, ortodoxo, ortografía, ortodoncia, etc.

Yo soy porteño (de la ciudad de Buenos Aires, Argentina) y allí orto se traduce literalmente como culo, es un término mundano y popular, que se refiere mas bien al ano que a las nalgas.

Lo usamos en frases como:

> **Me rompieron el orto**, por me cobraron muy caro *(fuimos a un restaurante y nos rompieron el orto, pagamos €500)*
>
> **Te voy a romper (o partir) el orto**, como amenaza física *(si volvés a mirar a mi novia te rompo el orto)*
>
> **Nos caímos de orto**, por nos sorprendimos *(nos dijo que está embarazada, y nos caímos de orto)*
>
> **Hacer algo como el orto** es hacer algo muy mal *(esta pared está pintada como el orto)*
>
> **Tener cara de orto**, es tener cara de enojado *(que te pasa que tenés esa cara de orto?)*
>
> **Estar como el orto**, es estar mal *(estoy como el orto, mi novia me dejó)*
>
> **Meter algo en el orto**, como amenaza *(si seguís tocando la guitarra te la voy a meter en el orto)*

Comment: Este post mejoraría mucho con un poco de formato.

Comment: Esta parece ser la respuesta correcta, pues como dice la we de [etimologias de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?orto), es un vulgarismo para referirse al _culo_ como el _recto_.

Answer (score 4):

Según contaban mis ancestros "orto" viene de huerta. Los inmigrantes italianos solían tener una pequeña huerta en la parte trasera de su jardín, de ahí la asociación. Una expresión anterior era "andá a cerrar el orto" la cual se le decía al italiano para que se vaya o se metiera en sus propios asuntos.

Actualmente perdura y significa "cerrá la boca".

Answer (score 1):

También se refiere a las nalgas porque los hombres dicen de las mujeres y las mujeres de los hombres: "Qué lindo orto..."

Cada vez se usa más en Uruguay. Es una palabra grosera, pero también se considera graciosa.

Comment: Parece uno de esos piropos típicos de obreros de la construcción que más que piropear dan vergüenza propia y ajena.

Answer (score 0):

*Orto* si bien puede ser por lo de huerta, también aparece en marineros de la antigüedad,donde orto es cuando amanece,sale el sol.."mira que lindo orto o lindo amanecer". Muchas de estas palabras provienen del lenguaje de marineros,como verga,rancho..

En Argentina se utiliza para referirse a "qué lindo trasero".  Ejemplo: "Mira el orto que tiene esa mina" (mina=mujer).  Y sobretodo se usa cuando el culo de la mujer es casi perfecto, paradito, redondo..con pantalones ajustados marcando aun mas sus nalgas..eso es un orto.

El origen del término se debe a que, cuando un astro asoma en el horizonte, parece ascender en ángulo "recto" con él (la trayectoria del astro y la línea del horizonte son "ortogonales"). "Orto" y "salida" son sinónimos. El antónimo de orto es *ocaso*. Por ende, amanecer (salida del astro,sol o luna) puede ser lindo para algunos..de ahí que si veo un culo lindo en vez de decir que lindo culo, digo "qué lindo orto". Lo que pudo haber comenzado como algo que se pudo decir sin ofender, se ha transformado en lo que conocemos hoy en día..También apoyo la posibilidad de *huerta* como apuntó Unorus Janco.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida..adjuntare mas informacion en cuanto al uso en lenguaje marinero..y si,en Argentina se utiliza para referirse a "que lindo trasero,ejemplo: "mira el orto que tiene esa mina" (mina,mujer) y sobretodo se usa cuando el culo de la mujer es casi perfecto,paradito,redondo..con pantalones ajustados marcando aun mas sus nalgas..eso es un orto.

Comment: El origen del término se debe a que, cuando un astro asoma en el horizonte, parece ascender en ángulo "recto" con él (la trayectoria del astro y la línea del horizonte son "ortogonales"). "Orto" y "salida" son sinónimos. El antónimo de orto es ocaso.Por ende,amanecer (salida del astro,sol o luna) puede ser lindo para algunos..de ahi que si veo un culo lindo en vez de decir que lindo culo,digo que lindo orto.Lo que pudo haber comenzado como algo que se pudo decir sin ofender,se ha transformado en lo que conocemos hoy en dia..Tambien apoyo la posibilidad de huerta como apunto Unorus Janco .